# Filledcurves aera below|above curve

Tags: gnuplot

I tried to use an example in the `demo` folder, my goal is to define a color area above and below my blue line
Here is what I get : 
[image]

And what I would like :
[image]

Code :

```
set style fill solid 0.50 noborder
set style data lines
set title "Fill area" 
set xrange [ 250.000 : 500.000 ] noreverse writeback
## Last datafile plotted: "silver.dat"
plot 'silver.dat' u 1:2:($3+$1/50.) w filledcurves above notitle, \
     '' u 1:2 w filledcurves lc rgb "light-salmon" notitle, \
     '' u 1:($3+$1/50.) lt 3 lw 2 title 'linemax"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, it should be noted that

```
'' u 1:2 w filledcurves lc rgb "light-salmon" notitle, \
```

will be interpreted as "filledcurves closed" by default.

The filled area of the desired plot in "salmon-pink" color is the envelope of the minimum of the two curves. This curve representing the envelope cannot be represented by a single filledcurves because it switches in the middle of the data points. As a workaround, how about using two filledcurves to represent the envelope by filling the second plot with the background color (white)?

```
set terminal wxt
set style fill solid 0.5 noborder
set style data lines
set title "Fill area" 
set xrange [ 250.000 : 500.000 ] noreverse writeback
## Last datafile plotted: "silver.dat"
plot 'silver.dat' u 1:2:($3+$1/50.) w filledcurves above notitle, \
     ''           u 1:($3+$1/50.)   w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "light-salmon" notitle, \
     ''           u 1:2:($3+$1/50.) w filledcurves below lt bgnd notitle, \
     ''           u 1:($3+$1/50.)   w lines lt 3 lw 2 title 'linemax"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records, there is a simpler solution. Additionally, it has the advantage of allowing transparent background.

**Code:**

```
### "partially" filledcurves with transparent background
reset session

set term pngcairo transparent
set output "SO69085000.png"

$Data <<EOD
250   20   4.472136
260   20   4.472136
270   18   4.242641
280   18   4.242641
290   20   4.472136
300   12   3.464102
310   26   5.099020
320   17   4.123106
330    8   2.828427
340    6   2.449490
350    8   2.828427
360   10   3.162278
370   20   4.472136
380   14   3.741657
390    8   2.828427
400   10   3.162278
410    9   3.000000
420    8   2.828427
430   10   3.162278
440   13   3.605551
450    9   3.000000
460    5   2.236068
470    7   2.645751
480   11   3.316625
500    7   2.645751
EOD

set style fill solid 0.5 noborder
set key noautotitles
set tics out

plot $Data u 1:2             w filledcurves   y=0 lc "green", \
     ''    u 1:($3+$1/50.):2 w filledcurves below lc "red", \
     ''    u 1:($3+$1/50.)   w lines lt 3 lw 2 title 'linemax'
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:** (screenshot of transparent PNG in front of checkerboard background)

[image]

Comment: actually, for the second plot line `'' u 1:2:($3+$1/50.) w filledcurves above lc "red"` would also work.